# Как сохранить часть html в word в альбомной ориентации?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ms-word

Я сохраняю таблицу в word  и она по умолчанию сохраняется в портретной ориентации, как сохранять ее в альбомной?
Вот код сохранения:

```
function exportHTML() {
  var header = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' " +
    "xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' " +
    "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>" +
    "<head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML to Word Document with JavaScript</title></head><body>"
  var footer = "</body></html>"
  var sourceHTML = header + document.getElementById("source-html").innerHTML + footer

  var source = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(sourceHTML)
  var fileDownload = document.createElement("a")
  document.body.appendChild(fileDownload)
  fileDownload.href = source
  fileDownload.download = 'Цифровой отчет.doc'
  fileDownload.click()
  document.body.removeChild(fileDownload)
}
```

https://codepen.io/anton-schneider/pen/ZEBxeZy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Класс секции должен быть оформлен строго как хочет Word. То есть Ваш вариант не совсем верный. Правильно будет обернуть вот так (без кавычек, но можете проверить и с ними):

```
<div class=Section2>...</div>
```

Потом Вы не подгружаете стили в документ. У Вас они есть в `head` в Вашем генераторе, но они не попадают в документ. Простым вариантом будет просто дописать их в вашу переменную `header`:

```
var header = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' " +
"xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' " +
"xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>" +
"<head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML to Word Document with JavaScript</title>" + `<style>
    @page Section2 {
        size: 841.7pt 595.45pt;
        mso-page-orientation: landscape;
        margin: 1.25in 1.0in 1.25in 1.0in;
        mso-header-margin: .5in;
        mso-footer-margin: .5in;
        mso-paper-source: 0;
    }

    div.Section2 {
        page: Section2;
    }
</style>` + "</head><body>"
```

После этих исправлений документ отобразился нормально:
[image: Изображение]
(Исправленный codepen: https://codepen.io/erriourru/pen/VwmXbKO)

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Все понятно и отлично работает!